# react typescript 'current' is not present in type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react and typescript.
I wanted to get the height of the div tag, so I used useRef.
However, I get a ts error in current.

```
Property 'current' is not present in type 'never'. ts(2339)
```

```
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (ref != null || ref.current != null) {
        setHeight(ref.current.clientHeight);
      }
    }, [user]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **This means that your condition `ref.current != null` will "NEVER" be true if `ref != null` is true**

I can see in your logic, you are trying to check if `ref.current` is not null before reference to `ref.current.clientHeight`

**So the correct condition should be:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (ref !== null && ref.current !== null) {
    setHeight(ref.current.clientHeight);
  }
}, [user]);
```

---

The `||` condition runs from left to right, if you want to keep using your condition then change the order to:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (ref.current !== null || ref !== null) {
    setHeight(ref.current.clientHeight);
  }
}, [user]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the errors are gone when you change the code to be:

```js
if (ref !== null && ref.current != null) {
    setHeight(ref.current.clientHeight);
}
```

I changed the `||` to `&&`.